# how to use backspace with process.stdin.setRawMode(true) nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

In nodejs when setting process.stdin.setRawMode(true)  the console functionalities get disabled but id like to use the backspace key on the output. something like clearline but for chars.

I have tried turning setRawMode() off then turning it on after the backspace action is finished. it worked for all input added AFTER setRawMode() was disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out a solution.

```
stdin.on("data", (data) => {    
    buffer += data;  
    if (data == "\b"){
    buffer = buffer.slice(0, buffer.length-2)
    stdout.clearLine(0);
    stdout.cursorTo(0);
    stdout.write(buffer);
    return;
}
```

If there is other solutions id appreciate it. Otherwise, this is functional.

Comment: hey i edited the answer. it was the time between clearline and stdout creates a flickering affects. come to think of it it looks cool. :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).